# Better way to add bootstrap elements to HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I've got some code that populates a warning, which ends up being this:

```
$('#alertContainer').html('<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><strong>Warning!</strong> No valid nodes were found for the path object.</div>');
```

I can't help but think this is a terrible, ghetto-ized solution, and that I'm simply not utilizing jQuery correctly to create this new element.

So, is there a better, cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Not really, unless you want to create the string in a variable that is a little easier to read than a one liner. Or put the html in page itself and just hide/show based on conditions. Adding html to page from js strings is not uncommon. if you have a lot of them can use a template engine script

Comment: @charlietfl Humm, it just seems so ugly. But its fine I guess, was just hoping that there was something better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to put your error code in a function or an object to clean up your script a bit and make it more readable.

Function method:

```
    function warningCodeCustom(noun) {
  var string = '<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">';
  string += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
  string += '<strong>Warning!</strong> No valid ' + noun + ' were found for the path object.';
  string += '</div>';
    return string;
  }
```

Called by: `$('#alertContainer').html(warningCodeCustom('node'));`

Object Method:
A really simple object breaks apart the code and could enhance readability or debugging later (possibly unnecessarily breaking apart your function for this application but I'm doing it anyway because the objects are pretty neat).

```
window.MyError = window.MyError || {};

MyError.Toolbox = MyError.Toolbox || {
  self : this,
  init : function() {
    //trigger the warning code bind
    self.warningCodeBind();
  },
  warningCodeBind : function() {
    //if there are no items on the page add content to our alert container
    if(!jQuery('.validNodes, .orOtherNodes').length) {
      jQuery('#alertContainer').html(self.warningCodeCustom());
    }
  },
  warningCodeCustom : function(noun) {
      var string = '<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">';
      string += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
      string += '<strong>Warning!</strong> No valid ' + noun + ' were found for the path object.';
      string += '</div>';
        return string;
      }
};

jQuery(window).load( function() {
    MyError.Toolbox.init();
});
```

I'm unsure what else your code does but the `.error()` functionality might be useful. [Article here](http://api.jquery.com/error/)

Comment: Funnily enough I have this solution in another part of my project, but only used it for parsing REALLY long entries (Modal->Bootstrap Tabbing->Tables->Data). I was hoping for a better solution, but I'll accept this as the best one in a bit if others don't turn up. Cheers!